# pm2 for running python script with arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, config, pm2

I am trying to run python script with arguments (I have to pass a path to the config for the script to run well).

I am doing it way:

```
pm2 start script.py --name appname --interpreter python3 -- config/xyz.yml
```

I have been using pm2 for quite some time and I know that custom parameters are after **--**

But with running python scripts it obviously doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 0):

I launch my scripts in the same manner without any problems. The only difference is that I pass the whole path to python interpreter (`/usr/bin/python3`) instead of just `python3`. Have you tried with the absolute path for `config/xyz.yml`? Relative path should also work though

Answer (score 0):

```
pm2 start script.py --name appname --interpreter python3 -- config/xyz.yml
```

This is the right way to call the argument. It was my fault, I have made mistake in reading those argument. So it works.